# isset vs try/catch on namespaces

Tags: php, xml, namespaces, rss, try-catch

I'm parsing RSS feeds and have a (sub)function that looks like this:

```
function nSpace($nSp, $type, $i){
  $namespaces = $i->getNameSpaces(true);
  $exp = explode(':', $nSp);
  try{
    $nameSp = $i->children($namespaces[$exp[0]]);
    $item[$type] = (string)$nameSp->$exp[1];
    return $item[$type];
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {  }
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve the namespace value, and will pass common RSS feed namespaces like "dc:date" or "content:encoded" for example as $nSp. The function works fine should the namespace exist in the XML, however the try{} is producing an 'Undefined Index' error in the first line when it doesn't.

Personally I'd rather run an `isset($i->children($namespaces[$exp[0]])){}` check instead of the try/catch, as I'm more familiar with that workflow, however this doesn't work (get a 'Can't use return value' error).

Few questions:

1. Shouldn't the try{} not produce error messages?
2. Is try/catch the best way?
3. Is there a way to do it with an if() instead?

Thanks.

Update:
Here is the (abreviated) call/usage for this function:

```
$rawFeed = file_get_contents($url);

try { $rss = new SimpleXMLElement($rawFeed); } catch (Exception $e) { }

foreach ($rss->channel->item as $i) {
    $item['link'] = isset($i->link) ? (string)$i->link : nSpace('dc:link', 'link', $i);
    $item['dateRaw'] = isset($i->pubDate) ? (string)$i->pubDate : nSpace('dc:date', 'date', $i);

// etc...
}
```

Comment: Is `$i->children()` even throw any execption?

Comment: @speccode It prints an error to the page - is that something different?

Comment: Can you show us code of `$i->children()` method? `$i` is class created by you?

Comment: @speccode Updated question - hopefully that helps. $i is $item, an item/story in the RSS feed.